# Turn off auto formatting for json files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have checked my preference multiple times and ensured that all options related to format-on-save are set to false. And yet everytime I save a .json file I see my file getting formatted.

Comment: Have you installed any extensions?

Comment: @seairth -- I had prettify-json installed. I tried disabling it but that didn't work.

Comment: Try uninstalling the extension entirely, restarting VSCode, and then see if the behavior goes away.

Comment: Tried that already. :(

Here are my settings :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oxqryk2ab35nno3/default-settings.json?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0wywuknhc89yo8/user-settings.json?dl=0

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest from here.  I can't reproduce it on my copy (v1.2.1).  Looking through the VSCode source, the stock install should only format JSON when performing an explicit "code format"  (e.g. Shift+Alt+F on Windows).  The actual registered command is "editor.action.format", so maybe you have another extension that is executing that command on save.  One way to test that might be to try a different installed language and see if it acts the same way.

Comment: Thanks for helping so much dude.. Appreciate much. Will see how to best isolate what extension might be triggering this.

Comment: **solved** : in `settings.json` remove **auto save** settings and reload vs code.

Comment: Save using `CTRL` + `K` to avoid formatting

Comment: A _little_ late, but there's `Format On Type` option...

Answer (score 198):

**EDIT: Uninstall the extension, there are many other far better maintained formatters out there (e.g. Beautify)**

OK, check if you have installed this extension: "JS-CSS-HTML formatter".

Now if you have, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, type "Formatter" and you should see an option that says Formatter Config.

After selecting that option, a file named formatter.json opens and all you do is edit the property (named onSave) from having true to being false.

Restart vs code and voilà!! It stopped auto formatting. (yay!!!!)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved my nerves! This should be way more promiment, as there are many posts  out in the internet asking the same question and vscode has no pointer in Settings to the formatter.json.

Comment: jesus christ im uninstalling this js-css-html formatter extension. not only does this override vscode's default onSave format option, it also formats js files incorrectly, notably optional chaining: `obj?.prop?.prop`

Comment: As @Binary said, just uninstall the damn JS-HTML-CSS Formatter extension and problem  gone.

Comment: @Binary I was getting too frustrated that no change in vs code settings was working for me. Then I landed on your comment and found the problem, thank you!

Comment: @Binary not just optional chaining, I think it also badly formats es6 private props. So yea agreed, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 96):

In Visual Studio Code, in order to stop autoformatting **only for your json files** add the following in `settings.json` file by opening **User Settings - Preferences.**

```
{   
    "[json]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false   
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be, yes. In 1.42.1 this had no effect. I had to set this to true for all other formats explicitely where I wanted autoformat, except [json] :( As soon as editor.formatOnSave was true for all (not inside a [...] block), I could not disable it for the json format.

Comment: @Satria thanks your small but critical comment saved me lightyears!

Comment: I'm on 1.63.1 and this same thing didn't work for me on yaml files.  I tried both "[yml]" and "[yaml]".

Answer (score 30):

In VS Code by default *Save without Formatting* is done by -

**on Windows :**
STEP 1 : Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then 
STEP 2 : Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

**on MAC :**
STEP 1 : Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then 
STEP 2 : Press <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: This is the most practical answer if you are just doing a small change to a file and don't want to mess up with the formatters.

Answer (score 27):

I am using the below version of VS Code

```
Version: 1.28.2 (user setup)
Commit: 7f3ce96ff4729c91352ae6def877e59c561f4850
Date: 2018-10-17T00:23:51.859Z
Electron: 2.0.9
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64
```

And turned it off with the following steps:

1. `CTRL+SHIFT+P`
2. Type `Settings`
3. Select `Preferences: Open User Settings`

Now follow these image instructions:

[image: Click Edit in settings.json]
[image: Change shown user setting values]

4. Select Save All
5. Restart VS Code

Comment: If this solution doesn't help then try to disable `vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter`, it helped in my case. Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16055

Comment: The alt text on your images is better than nothing, but instructions in images are not very accessible. Please consider putting textual instruction information in your answers in the future.

Comment: No, it should not be the accepted answer: the question was how to disable it for JSON files, this answer disable it for ALL files.

Answer (score 9):

look for Settings.json into "project/.vscode/settings.json"

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 9):

### Worth to note—You can `Save Without Formatting`.

I *like* the json formatting that is enabled by default **but** only want to disable/bypass it when editing *certain* files (i.e. I didn't want some massive json files reformatted/expanded after a one line update).

To exclude those certain files from auto formatting, I made my changes and **saved *without formatting*.**

Go into your VS Code keyboard shortcuts and see what `Save without formatting` is set to.

In my case (mac user) it is `CMD+K` followed by `S`. If it's not set, create your own custom shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

go to file -> **preferences** -> **settings** -> search for
**Editor: Auto Indent** and select **none** from drop down

also make this change in **setting.json
"editor.formatOnSave": false,**

yah this will work...

Answer (score 4):

## Solutions All In One

### solution 1

> config your `settings.json` file which in the `.vscode` folder, if not exists, just create one in the project root level directory.

[image]

1.1 disabled format on save for all files

```js
{
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

1.2 only disabled format on save for `.json` file

```js
{   
    "[json]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false   
    }
}
```

### solution 2

> just using the VS Code GUI

To open your user and workspace settings, use the following VS Code menu command:

On Windows/Linux: `File > Preferences > Settings`
On macOS: `Code > Preferences > Settings`

2.1 open workspace settings

> Command + Shift + P / Win + Shift + P

[image]

2.2 search the keyword (like, `json`) and set your config as you want

[image]

### refs

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answers here, there are settings other than `"editor.formatOnSave"` that might be having a similar effect, which you might also want to disable - for example, I had enabled the following in my User Preferences (settings.json):

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true
},
```

Comment: This was the setting that was giving me a headache. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

my format was set to CMD k + s by default for VS Code to save without formatting. you could try that out

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Disable the checkbox to disable the code formattor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the solution below didn't change the fact that my .json formatted itself when I saved it.

```json
// settings.json
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
```

The solution that works in my case is

[image: settings vs code]

Or add to the settings.json file (which does exactly the same thing)

```
"json.format.enable": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's for [lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter-0.2.3\out\src\formatter.json](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter),

try applying:

```
{
    "onSave": false,
    "javascript": {...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule that did it for me. I'm on VS Code `1.75.1`

```
"[json]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": false,
    },
},
```