# Visual Studio Code breaks Jekyll blog page layout

Tags: jekyll, visual-studio-code, r-markdown

I'm editing an `HTML` file from my `Jekyll` blog:

[image]

When I save the file, **Visual Studio Code** puts the layout reference in one line, breaking page's layout:

[image]

Is this a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was I have installed this extension: `JS-CSS-HTML Formatter`.

So, the solution is edit the `formatter.json` file and set the `onSave` property to `false`.

To do this, I have followed these steps:

1 - Press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and type `Formatter`:

[image]

2 - Change the value of the property `onSave` to `false`:

[image]

After editing the file, is necessary to restart **Visual Studio Code**.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955632/3090945) helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Disable auto formatting when saving the file in settings:

```
  "editor.formatOnSave": false
```

Comment: Also note that you can disable this just in html files by using a language specific setting: `"[html]": { "editor.formatOnSave": false }`

Comment: @MattBierner nice one, probably also for Markdown.

Comment: Change "editor.formatOnSave" setting didn't work. And set "[html]": { "editor.formatOnSave": false } neither.

Comment: Why oh why must all these "slick" editors resort to manual text file configuration? What is wrong with a GUI handling this for you?