# How do I stop VS Code from totally destroying my code on save?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've gone through formatting settings and stack overflow posts, I've toggled with a bunch of different settings and can't seem to find an answer to this. Nothing in `settings.json` seems to matter, maybe it's being overwritten somehow?

My tab spacing is set at 2 spaces and every time I restart my computer, something seems to happen to VS Code where saving a file adds a ton of weird spacing rules and tabs to 4 spaces, as you can see in the gif below that make my code terrible.

I don't want to go back to Atom or Sublime but the way VS Code is working for me right now, I can't use it in a professional context. Would love some help getting this figured out.

Thanks!

(image below is a gif, click it to see the style change on save)

[image]

Edit: installed packages in VS Code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: VS Code shouldn't do that on its own - do you have any beautifier extensions enabled?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53165624/9119186) will help you. You need to remove `Format on Save`

Comment: iF you press ctrl + , or cmd + , on mac I think, and go down to Text Editor, do you have 'Auto Indent' selected?

Comment: does it happen when you save the file?

Comment: @kemotoe yes it does

Answer (score 10):

This [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16055) turns out to have the answer. It happens when you have two settings that shouldn't conflict but do for some reason

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"javascript.format.enable": false
```

The solution was to uninstall `vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter` which you can do by searching for the author, `lonefy`, in your packages.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.
It's not Prettier, its "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter"
Just uninstall "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" extension,
then reload vscode, and it's done.
Also, no need to disable auto-format on save.

Comment: This is the right answer. It has nothing to do with prettier.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably Prettier that is doing this.

In your `settings.json` add these two lines:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,

"prettier.disableLanguages": [
    "jsx",
    "js"
],
```

Or just uninstall prettier

Answer (score 0):

its so simple just uninstall Prettier extensions that you have install. 
Press Extension Tab on your left sidebar (shift command X on mac) and choose your Prettier extension and uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) formats your code. Check your [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

> Format On Save
>
> Respects editor.formatOnSave setting.
>
> You can turn on format-on-save on a per-language basis by scoping the setting:
>
> ```
> // Set the default
> "editor.formatOnSave": false,
> // Enable per-language
> "[javascript]": {
> "editor.formatOnSave": true
> }
> ```