# VS Code format splitting comma-separated items in JSON file

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

VS Code wants to split comma separated arguments into separate lines.  I would prefer it not do this.  It only happens on one machine and I can't discover the setting that makes this happen.

As an example, consider this text in `settings.json`

```
"args": [
    "-q", "query",
    "-a", "answer"
]
```

I have format-on-save turned on, and every time I save the file, I get this

```
"args": [
    "-q",
    "query",
    "-a",
    "answer"
]
```

I would prefer that it leave these alone, like on all of my other machines.  Please note that I do not want to turn off auto-format, I just want this wrapping behavior to stop.

[New Info]
I copied the User settings `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json` from the machine that did not have the wrapping issues to the machine that did have the issues.  I'm not sure which setting it was, but that fixed the problem.  I'd still love to know which setting caused this behavior.  Both files are below.

### Wrapping Issues Settings

```
{
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    //"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 132,
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "deepIndent",
    "go.formatTool": "goimports",
    "go.liveErrors": {
        "enabled": true,
        "delay": 500
    },
    "go.vetOnSave": "workspace",
    "go.gocodeAutoBuild": true,
    "git.enableCommitSigning": true,
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.venvPath": "~/develop/virtualenv",
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "search.quickOpen.includeSymbols": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
}
```

### No Wrapping Issues Settings

```
{
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "deepIndent",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 132,
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "go.gocodeAutoBuild": true,
    "debug.enableAllHovers": true,
    "debug.inlineValues": true,
    "git.enableCommitSigning": true,
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "[python]": {

    },
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "python.venvPath": "~/develop/virtualenv",
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on",
}
```

### Combined settings with duplicates removed

```
paul-> cat settings.json.old.json settings.json |sort|uniq

        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "delay": 500
        "enabled": true,
    "[python]": {
    "debug.enableAllHovers": true,
    "debug.inlineValues": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 132,
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "deepIndent",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.exclude": {
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "git.enableCommitSigning": true,
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true,
    "go.formatTool": "goimports",
    "go.gocodeAutoBuild": true,
    "go.liveErrors": {
    "go.vetOnSave": "workspace",
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.venvPath": "~/develop/virtualenv",
    "search.quickOpen.includeSymbols": true,
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    //"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
    },
{
}
}{
```

Comment: To my knowledge, it isn't possible to disable specific formatting behaviors. The only recourse is to disable auto-formatting for `.json` files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057725/turn-off-auto-formatting-for-json-files-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @ifconfig I don't see this behavior on my desktop machine, only on my laptop with a much smaller screen

Comment: Is it possible that this is then an issue with VSCode line wrapping? Otherwise, that description doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I just added a little extension called 'Split line', it seems to do the job ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180702/836330 for a similar case.

Enable this setting: `JSON > Format: Keep Lines`

With that setting enabled - it is coming in v1.70

```json
"args": [
    "-q", "query",
    "-a", "answer"
]
```

will stay exactly that way.  Lines with multiple values or multiple key/value pairs will be "kept" as is.

Comment: Works in 1.71.  Thanks!